# Loading Large Files as Dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pickle, word2vec

My first question on stackoverflow :)

I am trying to load a pertained vectors from Glove vectors and create a dictionary with words as keys and corresponding vectors as values. I did the usual naive method to this:

```
fp=open(wordEmbdfile)
self.wordVectors={}
# Create wordVector dictionary
for aline in fp:
    w=aline.rstrip().split()
    self.wordVectors[w[0]]=w[1:]
fp.close()
```

I see a huge memory pressure on Activity Monitor, and eventually after trying for an hour or two it crashes.

I am going to try splitting in multiple smaller files and create multiple dictionaries.

In the meantime I have following questions:

1. To read the word2vec file, is it better if I read the gzipped file using `gzip.open` or uncompress it and then read it with plain open.
2. The word vector file has text in first column and float in the rest, would it be more optimal to use genfromtext or loadtext from numpy?
3. I intend save this dictionary using chicle, I know loading it is going to be hard too. I read the suggestion to use shelve, how does it compare to cPickle in loading time and access time. May be its better to spend some more time loading with cPickle if improve future accesses (if cPickle does not crash, with 8G RAM), Does anyone have some suggestion on this?

Thanks!

Comment: First, is this working right for a limited number of lines, say 10 or 100?  Does it work to read the whole file and save just part of each line?

Comment: `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` do basically the same thing - read line by line, split the line into a list, and collect everything into a list.  Finally they convert the big list to an array.  Memory consumption is going to be similar.

Comment: I believe you can save yourself the call to `rstrip` and just do `w=aline.split()`

Comment: somebody edited the code, but now the indentation looks wrong

Comment: BTW, if you want the value to be a float you still need to convert it (now it's a string).

Comment: I would recommend [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which uses a fast parser written in C. It should be able to select appropriate string/float types for each column automatically, although it will be faster if these are pre-specified. There are also options to read the file in chunks if you're hitting memory limits. It even supports on-the-fly decompression for gzipped files. [See this Q/A for a related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29678154/1461210).

Comment: In terms of saving the data, pickling is very slow and inefficient for numeric data. I'd recommend you use HDF5, which supports fast on-the-fly compression and decompression. Again, pandas makes this easy using the [`pandas.read_hdf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) methods.